# PHP Code not able to display data from mysql database

Tags: php, html

I am trying to prepare a php code to fetch data from a database and display it in the browser upon entering a keyword in the input field. The name of file in which code is stored is resu.php The code is as follows

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
            <title>fade</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <form action="resu.php" method="get">
                     <div class="row" id="bg">
                         <div class="col-sm-1" id="resdoodle">
                             <a href="index.html"><font color="#FF0000">f</font><font color="#FFA500">a</font><font color="#008000">d</font><font color="#0000FF">e</font></a>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-sm-6" id="searchbx2">
                             <div class="input-group">
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="boxstyle2" required>
                                 <span class="input-group-btn">
                                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" name="search_btn" value="GO" id="btnstyle2">
                                 </span>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="result"> 
                    <?php
                         $_con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "augustus", "password");
                         mysqli_select_db($_con,"webdata");
                         if(isset($_GET['search_btn']))
                         {
                             $search=$_GET['search'];
                             $_sql1="select * from websited where stitle like '%$search%'";
                             $rs1=mysqli_query($_sql1);
                             while($resul=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs1))
                             {
                                 echo "<a href='".$resul[slink]."'><font size='4' color='#0000cc'> <b>".$resul[stitle]."</b> </font></a><br>";
                                 echo "<font size='3' color='#006400'> <b>".$resul[slink]."</b> </font><br>";
                                 echo "<font size='3' color='#666666'> <b>".$resul[sdesc]."</b> </font><br>";
                             }
                         }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="tether.min.js"></script>
                <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          </body>
    </html>
```

The code is detecting the presence of keyword YouTube in database but not able to display the entries. Please help.

Comment: `$rs1=mysqli_query($_sql1);` that should be a syntax error. and the other array accesses too `$resul[slink]`

Comment: @Dharman Why should it be a syntax error?

Comment: You are passing only 1 argument to the `mysqli_query` function. `slink` and others should not be PHP constants, rather they should be strings.

Comment: @Dharman Please explain a little more. I am not able to understand what you said about the php constants. Also explain how can I declare the variables as strings.                                    Edit: Thanks, I just noticed the flaw. The problem was, as you pointed out, the mysqli_query function.

Comment: Change it to `$resul['slink']`

Answer (score 0):

As @Dharman pointed out, the flaw in the code was the `mysqli_query` function on line 34.
The proper code should be

```
$rs1=mysqli_query($_con,$_sql1);
```

And `$resul[slink]` should be corrected to `$resul['slink']`
The same with all other variables.